# How to connect ghostscript with imagecreatefrompng in PHP?

Tags: php, image, process, pipe, ghostscript

I am currently using ghostscript, via `exec()` from PHP, to create a PNG image that is saved to a file.

And then I use `imagecreatefrompng()` to load it into PHP. I am wondering if there is a way to directly connect these without first saving it to a file and then reading it from a file. Does this work with the expect:// wrappers? If so could somebody provide an example? I am not sure about the syntax.

Another solution may perhaps be with `imagecreatefromstring()` if one can get the image file as a string from ghostscript. I am looking for an example of how to do this. The image files I create are not that large, typically 600 x 150 pixels.